# I am getting Uncaught ReferenceError: wysiwygSetup is not defined

Tags: magento2, magento2.2.2

**Please anyone can help me here, I am getting the require undefined in js, below is my code. Thank you**

My code:

```
          <script>
        require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/translate",
            "mage/adminhtml/events",
            "mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup"
        ], function(jQuery) {
            wysiwygCompanyDescription = new wysiwygSetup("company_description", {
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "200px",
                "plugins": [{
                    "name": "image"
                }],
                "tinymce4": {
                    "toolbar": "formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap",
                    "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                }
            });
            wysiwygCompanyDescription.setup("exact");
        }); 
    </script>
```

**and the error is:**

```
(index):725 Uncaught ReferenceError: wysiwygSetup is not defined
    at (index):725
    at Object.execCb (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:1650)
    at Module.check (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:1113)
    at db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:132
    at db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:1156
    at each (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:57)
    at Module.emit (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:1155)
    at Module.check (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:917)
    at Module.<anonymous> (db2cfb207124dfa2df050f1ef1a6e743.js:1113)
```

Comment: which magento version you're using ?

Comment: i am using magento 2.2.3

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issue and after debugging I found out that when I change ***tynimce4*** with just **tynimce** it works fine,

so the solution you should use **tynimce** without the 4 :

```
    <script>
        require([
            "jquery",
            "mage/translate",
            "mage/adminhtml/events",
            "mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup"
        ], function (jQuery) {
            wysiwygCompanyDescription = new wysiwygSetup("company_description", {
                "width": "100%",
                "height": "200px",
                "plugins": [{
                    "name": "image"
                }],
                "tinymce": {
                    "toolbar": "formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap",
                    "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table",
                }
            });
            wysiwygCompanyDescription.setup("exact");
        });
    </script>
```

The root cause of the issue is that magento no more use tynimce4 instead it moved to 5 so things changed :
with your initial script it tries to access this.config.tinymce['content_css'], which is not defined, and so the error

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to use wysiwyg editor.

**HTML :**

```
<textarea id="company_description" name="company_description"></textarea>
```

**Script :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/adminhtml/wysiwyg/tiny_mce/setup'
], function(jQuery){
    wysiwyg = new wysiwygSetup('company_description', {
        'width':'100%',
        'height':'300px',
        'plugins':[{'name':'image'}],
        'tinymce4':{'toolbar':'formatselect | bold italic underline | alignleft aligncenter alignright | bullist numlist | link table charmap','plugins':'advlist autolink lists link charmap media noneditable table contextmenu paste code help table'
        }
    });
    wysiwyg.setup('exact');
});
</script>
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Error is not showing in console but the button is also not showing

Comment: You mean texteditor is working without buttons ?

Comment: I've updated my answer, Please check that will work definitely. :)

Comment: Did you tried above solution ?

Comment: Yes but its not woking.

Comment: I've updated code, Please copy that again and check once

Comment: I've tried and that is working correctly in forms

Comment: I change your code but still sowing error.

Comment: After changing code please clear Magento cache and flush it

Comment: i did this....and i also run upgrade command

Comment: any errors coming in console ?